# How to setup bootstrap progress bar on openlayers 3.9.0

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, openlayers-3

I want to show a progress bar when till the layers load on open layer 3.9.0 any hints or direction would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like:

```
var
    tile_loading = 0, 
    tile_loaded = 0, 
    tiles_loaded_all = false
;
yourTileLayer.getSource().on('tileloadstart', function(evt){
    ++tile_loading;
});
yourTileLayer.getSource().on('tileloadend', function(evt){
    ++tile_loaded;
    if(tile_loaded === tile_loading){
        tile_loading = 0;
        tile_loaded = 0;
        tiles_loaded_all = true;


    }
});
```

The official example - http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/examples/tile-load-events.html